# Preview different Locales of UIView wrapped to SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swiftui, locale

I started trying out SwiftUI preview for UIKit views, (by using `UIViewRepresentable`) and encountered a tricky issue with this setup. I tried to preview the wrapped view in a different Locale using the `environment` modifier but it just doesn’t work.

Here is a code snippet of the preview:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            SimpleLabelViewWrapper()
                .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 120, height: 50))
                .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "fr"))
                .previewDisplayName("UIKit")
            SimpleSwiftUIText()
                .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
                .padding()
                .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "fr"))
                .previewDisplayName("SwiftUI")
        }

    }
}
```

- `SimpleLabelViewWrapper` conforms to `UIViewRepresentable` and returns a `UIView` with a `UILabel` as a subview.
- `SimpleSwiftUIText` is simply a SwiftUI View with `Text` as a body.

The output preview looks like this: [Preview screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDwWZ.png)

**Findings**

`Text` has an initialiser:

> `init(_ key: LocalizedStringKey, tableName: String? = nil, bundle: Bundle? = nil, comment: StaticString? = nil)`

The `LocalizedStringKey` is used to map the value to the localisation table. However,  this is not probably used when you simply wrap a UIKit view to SwiftUI as I suspect UIKit views still uses `UILabel.text`or `UILabel.attributedText`  (i.e. `UILabel` doesn’t get mapped to `Text`) to display a string that is not of `LocalizedStringKey` type hence it defaults to the base language.

This might be a limitation when not using pure `SwiftUI` but it would be better to fully understand why it doesn't work or if there is a workaround.